# Ambiguous cache keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, caching, data-structures

I have a data structure which is like this (the real has more nodes levels):

```
  -------Node 1------           
  |               |
  |               |
Node A:         Node B:
-element 1A1    -element 1B1
-element 1A2    -element 1B2
```

Each element is identified by parents IDs. Each node and element may store or may don't store some value. The values are inherited from parents. So when I want to find value for 1A2, I:

```
1) check if value for 1A2 exists
2) if not, check if value for A exists
3) if not, check if value for 1 exists
4) save the first found value
```

The structure is stored in database and it's much more complex. So the problem is that database queries are too slow. But this structure doesn't change often, so I decided to build a server-side cache for it. The cache is removed after any changes in the structure and is rebuild when there is the first attempt to read value of some element. The problem is that, when the cache keys are like this:

```
"1-A-1" for 1A1 value
"1-A-2" for 1A2 value
"1-A" for A value
"1" for 1 value
```

1A has value and 1A1 doesn't have value but 1A2 does, the first cache stored is "1-A". Then when I try to find value for 1A2, I first search through the cache and there I find the key "1-A" which fits for my element as these are right nodes. So I don't make any query to database as I assume, the value found in the cache is right. But it is not.
How can I solve this problem? Is there any solution? I want to make the least queries as possible, but I always want to find the exact value for given element.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You look for 1A2 and it exists in the cache but you choose to return 1A? Or is 1A2 not yet in the cache and that's any 1A is returned without checking for 1A2?

Comment: The problem happens when 1A2 is not in the cache but 1A is already there.

Comment: So what you may need is negative caching also (ie caching that entries don't exist). In that case, you can start lookup on 1A2, if it does not exist in the cache try getting it from DB. If it's there, cache, if it's not cache that it's not. The next lookup of 1A2 will know for sure whether it exists or not by just looking in cache.

Comment: I though about this, but it would give me about 500k cache entries (just a few elements have value, most are stored in nodes). But unfortunately it seems that it is the only way.